# Data is not retrieving from Firebase database

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angular2-services

This is my component. I don't know why data is not retrieving from firebase. Can anyone tell me the wrong in this code?

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFireDatabase, FirebaseListObservable } from 'angularfire2/database';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-dashboard',
  templateUrl: './dashboard.component.html'
})
export class DashboardComponent implements OnInit {
  tasks: FirebaseListObservable<any[]>;

  constructor(
    public afdb: AngularFireDatabase
  ) { 
      this.tasks = this.afdb.list('scheduler/')
      console.log("Console", this.tasks);      
  }

  ngOnInit() {
   }
```

}

When I execute this code, I'm getting this console -

```
 {query: Reference, update: ƒ, set: ƒ, push: ƒ, remove: ƒ, …}
 auditTrail
 :
 ƒ (events){query: Reference, update: ƒ, set: ƒ, push: ƒ, remove: ƒ,      …}
 auditTrail
 :
 ƒ (events)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem you have with this code is that you are trying to output an observable to the console when what you probably want to do is log the data the observable is watching.

So you probably want to change:

```
    console.log("Console", this.tasks);
```

to this:

```
    this.tasks.subscribe(items => {
        console.log(items);  
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

The final code that I got the answer is -

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFireDatabase, FirebaseListObservable } from 'angularfire2/database';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-dashboard',
  templateUrl: './dashboard.component.html'
})

export class DashboardComponent implements OnInit {
  tasks: FirebaseListObservable<any[]>;

  constructor(
    public afdb: AngularFireDatabase
  ) { 
      this.afdb.list('scheduler/').valueChanges().subscribe(items => {
         console.log("items", items);
      })
  }

  ngOnInit() {
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can retrive the data from firebase using this way

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFireDatabase } from 'angularfire2/database';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-coupons',
  templateUrl: './coupons.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./coupons.component.css']
})
export class CouponsComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(
    private afdb: AngularFireDatabase
  ) { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }
  getData() {
    this.afdb.list('scheduler/').snapshotChanges()
    .subscribe(values=>{
        if(values) {
         values.map(val=>{
           let data = val.payload.val(); //get data
           let uid = val.key;
        });
       }
    });

  }

}
```